# dynamic titles and description

Tags: php, html, title

OK I would like dynamic titles and descriptions for each page. The page itself it php but it populates from a DB different content based off your selections. This is the current code as you can see they set it up to make it facebook friendly lord only know why when being search engine friendly is a lot higher priority. Is there a way to port those 2 variables for name / desc into the html title and description make it a lot easier for google and others to index the page. Their algorithm is rather hit and miss where it is telling me over 340 links are the same.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$build_data['name'];?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$build_data['desc'];?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=PATH;?>upload_building_image/<?=$build_image['image'];?>" />
<?=$general->pagemeta('Property_Detail');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="title" content="<?=$build_data['name'];?>" />
<meta name="description" content="<?=$build_data['desc'];?>" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$build_data['name'];?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$build_data['desc'];?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=PATH;?>upload_building_image/<?=$build_image['image'];?>" />
<?=$general->pagemeta('Property_Detail');?>
```

Comment: that doesn't appear to have the required effect. Inspect element is giving me <meta name="title" content=""> and <meta name="description" content="">

Comment: Hmm... I updated the code, could you try it once more please?

Comment: Awesome that is much closer, it does populate the the content=" portion when you inspect element for both but not the page title when you look at the tab itself in the browser. Currently it is Page Name | Site Name. I need the title from here and site name. (Much like this post is done php-dynamic titles and description - stackoverflow.com) Side no I do see that you can set title in my CMS but it doesn't have the level of refinement I'm looking at here but should be a way to override the existing correct. Thanks I really appreciate the expertise bad elance experience and this is the results.

Comment: managed to solve it with a php echo command.for anyone else finding this. <title><?php echo $build_data['name'];?><?php echo ' |';?> <?php echo $build_data['street_address'];?><?php echo ' | Site name';?></title>